# JBoss: Find out what component fails to return connection to the pool

Tags: jboss, wildfly, datasource

I have statistics enabled for a data source and can see that there are much more active connections than expected. I suppose some deployment on the server misses to call Connection.close() thus keeping connections active and not returning them to the pool.
I would like to ask for your advice regarding the method I can use to figure out who on server is keeping connections active. There are several deployments that are using a particular data source.

Profiler? JMX? anything else?

Thanks,
Valery

[image]

Answer (score -1):

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/309913
Seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

> Resolution To enable the cached connection manager (CCM) to identify a
> connection leak:
>
> 1. Enable the CCM for the datasource. It defaults to true if it is not explicitly specified but you may set use-ccm="true" explicitly.
> 2. Verify that  exists in the jca subsystem and set debug="true"
>
> Setting debug="true" will:
>
> Log an INFO message indicating that JBoss is "Closing a connection for
> you. Please close them yourself" Generate a stacktrace for the code
> where the leaked connection was first opened. Close the leaked
> connection